# Prove that the sum of all simple roots is a root

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\Delta$ be an indecomposable root system in a real inner product space $E$, and suppose that $\Phi$ is a simple system of roots in $\Delta$, with respect to an ordering of $E$. If $\Phi = \{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_l \}$, prove that 
$$
\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_l \in \Delta
$$

I know that any positive root $\gamma$ may be written as a sum of simple roots, and furthermore that every partial sum is itself a root, but I am unsure if that will help me or not. Any hints to get me started?

Edit: I had an idea since I posted but am now stuck on the proof. We know that $(\alpha_i, \alpha_j) \leq 0$ for $i \neq j$. We also know that if $(\alpha_i,\alpha_j) < 0$, then $\alpha_i + \alpha_j$ is a root. My thoughts are an induction-style proof: If $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) < 0$, then $\alpha_1+\alpha_2 \in \Delta$. Assume that $\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_{l-1}$ is a root then
$$
(\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_{l-1}, \alpha_l) = (\alpha_1, \alpha_l) + \cdots + (\alpha_{l-1},\alpha_l) < 0
$$
Hence, 
$$
\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_l \in \Delta
$$
However, I am not sure how to prove these are strict inequalities. I assume it has to do with the fact that $\Phi$ is indecomposable, but I am unsure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

First, I would let $\Phi$ be a base for an indecomposable root system, and choose labels for the elements of $\Phi$ according to the following algorithm:

Suppose you have chosen $\Phi_k:=\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k\}$ such that the corresponding root system $\Delta_k$ is indecomposable (when $k=1$ this is automatic). Then, there exists $\alpha_{k+1}\in\Phi$ such that $\Phi_{k+1}$ is a base for an indecomposable root system $\Delta_{k+1}$. Indeed, otherwise $$\mathrm{span}(\Phi_k)\perp \mathrm{span}(\Phi\backslash\Phi_k),$$
so $\Delta$ is **not** indecomposable, a contradiction.

This is enough to obtain strict inequality since, by construction, we must have $(\alpha_j,\alpha_l)<0$ for some $j<l$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still confused by the strict inequality: why do we get that $(\alpha_j,\alpha_l) < 0$ by construction? I'm very new to root systems so I am probably missing something obvious :)

Comment: Choosing $\alpha_{k+1}\in \Delta$ such that $\Delta_{k+1}$ is indecomposable is equivalent to choosing $\alpha_{k+1}$ such that $(\alpha_{j},\alpha_{k+1})<0$ for some $j\leq k$.

Comment: Recall, a root system is decomposable if $\Delta=\Delta'\sqcup\Delta''$ with $\Delta',\Delta''\neq\emptyset$ and $\Delta'\perp\Delta''$.